# Cannot find function variable name in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, promise

I've created following AngularJS code, but I've found `Error: Can't find variable: modifyCustomerAgent` error when I render call `modifyCustomer()` my code. Please let me know what's wrong. Thanks.

```
function modifyCustomer() {
    return modifyCustomerAgent(modifyCustomerData, true).then(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}

$scope.modifyCustomerAgent = (saveFormData, isUpgrade) => {
    return {
        property: 'value'
    };
}
```

Comment: `modifyCustomerAgent` needs to be a promise, i think

Comment: @Siddharth damn, I missed that. Please write as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```js
$scope.modifyCustomerAgent = (saveFormData, isUpgrade) => {
  return Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      resolve ({
        property: 'value'
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Good answer.. :)